# I am getting an error installing tidyverse on R studio

Tags: r

I am trying to install the `tidyverse` package, but I get the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

I have done everything that I found, nothing seems to help. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `dependencies = TRUE`

Comment: If *"there is no package called ‘Rcpp’"*, the solution is to install it? :)

Comment: I install Rcpp, It does not work.